# How to add a Brother printer manually?

Tags: networking, printing

I switched printers (from Samsung to Brother), both are WiFi enabled and connected to a network `10.0.0.0/24`.

My Android phone (Samsung 9+) is on another network within the same LAN (`10.1.0.0/24`). It can ping the printer so routing is OK.

The Brother print plug-in fails to find the printer automatically. This is understandable as they are on different VLANs.

**How can I add such a "remote" printer?** The Samsung plugin had an explicit "Add printer" entry, which I do not see in the Brother's one.

Comment: Never been able to get the Brother plugin to see my printer either, but I just use the default Cloud Print plugin and it works fine adding manually

Comment: @acejavelin: I tried to use the default printing service which allows me to manually add a printer. The printer is recognized but when I want to get back to the main page of the service, it crashes. I managed to use Brother iPrint&something app which allows a manual addition and I manage to print from there. This is a pain in the bottom, though, as it is not recognized as a target when printing (I have to print from within the app)